# CSS flex column order - Chrome issue?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to "mobilize" a site I am working on, I set it up so that the text boxes are in a column with display: flex, flex-direction: column. I then ordered the divs as they need to be displayed differently on a mobile device than on a regular browser.

`This is my result:` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpBvyg

It looks to be formatting correctly in FF so far as I can tell. But in Chrome, it doubles the height, at least it is for me. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Let me know if I am missing any details to clarify.

Thank you!

Comment: add the code, not a codepen, btw your codepen shows a blank screen

Comment: You have to scroll down to see the html markup. It appears to have worked for Carson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `br` elements in between your `div` elements which are child elements of your flexbox. When you reorder the `div` elements you aren't ordering your `br` elements, which are occupying the top of the page and creating the blank space.

I suggest removing all of the `br` elements and trying to get your non-mobile page to look good without them.

Here is a codepen with all of the BR's removed. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGqxzm

No space is being occupied at the top.

If you post some more code I can give you some more advice about how to have this work on both mobile and desktop more easily.

Comment: Well colour me stupid. Thank you. I have fixed it now. I just incorporated the line breaks into the divs. That fixed everything. Thank you again!